# Windows XP will not read DVD movie

Tags: windows-xp, dvd

I like watching the Disney "Inside Out" movie on my Xbox.

When I tried to put it into my laptop running Windows XP, it failed to load. Windows doesn't even recognize the disc.

XP recognizes an older Lion King disc. What is wrong?

If I need a new codec, can someone point me to a free one?

I've tried it in VLC and Windows Media Player.

Comment: This question currently is way to broad.  What other applications have you tried other then just VLC?  Windows Media Player, does not count, because it does not support the newer codecs that are used (by default).

Comment: Download Windows Media Player Classic. It is an extremely versatile software and contains almost ALL the codecs that are used nowadays. It is also an Open Source Software. Download it from here: https://mpc-hc.org/

Comment: @yoyo_fun downloaded, but it doesn't even show that a disk is inserted on Windows. Other discs work fine.

Comment: Is it a DVD or is it BluRay? Is that an Xbox One or Xbox 360?

Comment: @music2myear DVD. Using an Xbox 360.

Answer (score 1):

Two of the most common issues with movie DVD's (you didn't mention if it was a retail DVD or a burned copy) not playing in a pc are:

1. Region issues: DVD are recorded with security that only allows them to play in certain regions and pc dvd drives do not usually have as large a list of regions natively with the drive and prevent recognition of disk that are out of region. Unless you have software to apply additional regions, they will not play.
2. DVD Type Compatibility: Movie disk players and Xbox's have dvd drives that play a larger range of disks since retail movie and game dvd come in a large variety of type. Pc's on the other hand, have dvd drives that do not play nearly as large of a range of disk types.
   ie: a. A pc dvd drive may only play dvd+R and not -R disks
       b. A pc dvd drive typically do not play all types such as Dual 
          sided dvd's, dual layer dvd's or multi-layer dvd's.

Since you mentioned the machine you are trying to play it on is a laptop with Windows XP (which is an older machine) I would imagine the dvd drive in that installed in it does not play this type of disk. To know for sure you would have to look up your dvd drive model specification from the manufacturer and compare this with the dvd type you have. This specific movie disk you have mentioned (Inside Out) comes on at least 5 known versions ranging from a 3-Disc Blu-ray 3D Combo Pack to a single disc Digital HD / Digital SD in which I have not seen one that was single layer. I is possible your player does not play this disk type.

The Lion King movie however is a 22 year old movie that came out in 1994 and if it was one of the original dvd's and not a re-release then it would not be a dual layer or multi-layer dvd and possibly not even a dual sided dvd if it was an original disk release.

Most of the time if it is a layer incompatibility with a dvd disk, a computer drive will not even recognize that the disk is there or present.

Comment: Hmm.. what is the difference between +R and -R?

Comment: +R and -R disk types refer to the record-ability of the disk itself. It was used more as an example of compatibility issues and had nothing much to do with playing disks today as most modern drives and players will play both recorded types. Back in the Windows XP days and before it wasn't always true that they would play both types but retail movies and games do not use or need the +R capabilities anyway. Some pc dvd RW (Read/Write) drives have not been able to write (record) to both types but that is faded from being an issue in the last 6-7 years.

Comment: you say that there is no single-layer. My DVD is burned only on one side.

Comment: You didn't mention that your disk in question was burned or a copy, which is what it sounds like your saying. That would be critical info as to determine why it wouldn't be recognized. Being written (burned) to one side does not determine its type. There are dvd burners or writers on the market that will write to dual layer dvd. They generally don't burn or write to both sides of the layers. Ones that write to both sides of DL's are very rare and expensive drives. You can not tell by looking at a dvd if it has one or two layers. The cheaper DVD's today with 4.7GB capacities are single layer.

Comment: The typical SL dvd's of today are 4.7GB if the capacity is anything other than 4.7GB then it would be a DL. SL disk are not generally used in the video industry unless they only contain the movie. Usually there are some interactive content and SL's are too small.

Comment: SL's are too small to use for video production since most studios record the disks in lossless formats and to date have not adopted lossy formats even though digital downloads from Netflix and Amazon or now available in lossy formats mainly to limit download bandwidth.

Comment: this is unrelated, but if I copy all the files off my disc on a newer computer that reads it, can I play that folder like it is a disc on XP without issues?